# Is there any way to store values of each iteration in for loop in new variable separately?

Tags: python

What I want to do is trying to get different values of `p_y_given_x` for different `sigma2_n` separately in each line? When I use append it gives me result in one array. But I want separate results for each 0.2 for `p_y_given_x`.

Is there any hint for me?

```
for sigma2_n in np.arange(0.2,0.9):

    p_y_given_x= np.exp(-(y_new-alphabet[t])**2/2/sigma2_N)
```

the result should be like this

```
p_y_given_x=[2 1 5 6 7
             5 7 8 9 0]

p_y_given_x2=[3 5 8 7
             5 4 7 0]

p_y_given_x3=[1 4 9 6
             5 3 4 5]
```

......
for each value of `sigma2_N`, it gets value for `p_y_given_x`, but I want to get this new value in the different name, for example:

`p_y_given_x1`
`p_y_given_x2`
`p_y_given_x3` and so on
is there any solution for it with a for loop?

If I use `append()` function it attaches all the results in one array and I don't want this, the result will be

```
i=[]     
for sigma2_n in np.arange(0.2,0.9):
    p_y_given_x= np.exp(-(y_new-alphabet[t])**2/2/sigma2_N)
    i.append(sigma2_N)

[p_y_given_x1,p_y_given_x2,p_y_given_x3,....]
```

Comment: *Why* don't you want a list? Why is  `p_y_given_x1` preferred to `p_y_given_x[0]`?

Comment: You could use a dict.

Comment: yes for me doesn't matter, in my task, I should compare these results with each other and make a conclusion that's why I need them separately, how can i do it with dict?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the different lists in a dict and identify each list using a key like below:

```
d = {}
i = 0
for sigma2_n in np.arange(0.2,0.9):
    d['p_y_given_x'+str(i)] = np.exp(-(y_new-alphabet[t])**2/2/sigma2_N)
    i += 1
```